# Whats the best idea for set a listview in a scrollview?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a problem with `listView` inside a `scrollView` , I know that it cant work correctly by default, but i have to do this. and the question is that how can I do this? any idea?!

i use this way :
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3495908/5336567)

but it doesn't work for me!

thanks!

Comment: Why you need a ListView inside a ScrollView? ListView already scrolls itself.

Comment: @m0skit0 Good question! my list view is not complete whole screen, its just a part of screen. I want when user scroll screen, list view items show too and expand list view